# Selecting number of CPU cores in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am comparing performance of OpenMP with that of OpenCL on CPUs and my system has 8 cores. But I need comparisons for 2, 4, 6 and 8 cores respectively. I can activiate number of cores in OpenMP through "set_num_threads(n)" function or an environment variable; But I dont know how could I do same in OpenCL, is there alternative of OpenMP set_num_threads API in OpenCL ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard way to do this. OpenCL will try to use all of the resources available on an OpenCL device.

One possibility you could look into is the [device fission extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/ext/cl_ext_device_fission.txt). It allows you to divide the device (in this case the CPU) into smaller logical devices. It is currently supported on CPUs by AMD's implementation at least. Do a search and you'll find some more resources from AMD as well.

Comment: Thanks I could do it successfully now :)