# Limit the number of compute units used by OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I need to limit the number of compute units used by my opencl application.
I'm running it on a CPU that has 8 compute units, I've seen that with CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS.

The execution time I get with OpenCL is much less than 8 times the normal algorithm without OpenCL (is like 600 time faster). I want to use just 1 compute units because I need to see the  real improvement with the same code optimized by OpenCL.

It's just for testing, the real application will continue to use all the compute units.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163962/selecting-number-of-cpu-cores-in-opencl

Comment: I've seen that, but currently device fission is not supported on my CPU (intel i7 920 on Mac). I've also tried with export CPU_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS=1 but has no effect :/

Comment: Maybe trying to set this in OpenCL is not the right way to go, then. Did you you explore ways to deactivate some cores of the CPU in your OS?

Comment: Thanks, at the end i've disabled hyper-threading and all the cores directly in the BIOS.
It seems that OpenCL alone using a single core is much faster than the same algorithm without OpenCL. In my case is about 7x faster.

Comment: you can change main process affinity to not use all cores. this works for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using CPUs, Why dont you try using the OpenCL device fission extension ?

Device Fission allows you to split up a computer unit into sub-devices. You can then create a command queue to the subdevice and enqueue kernels only to that subset of your CPU cores,

You can divide your 8 core device into 8 subdevices of 1 core each for example.

Take a look at the Device Fission example in the AMD APP SDK.